# Refresh contents of a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a div that displays text from a php session:

```
<div id="sessioncontent">
<?php if (isset( $_SESSION['returntext'])){ echo  $_SESSION['returntext'];} ?>
</div>
```

I have a javascript method that calls another php script which changes the text within that session variable. At the end of the method, I want the div to refresh so that the new text within the session is echoed. I have tried the following line but it doesnt work:

```
document.getElementById("sessioncontent").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sessioncontent").innerHTML;
```

Comment: when your webpage hits a users browser, the PHP is no longer there. It  is processed into front-end code (html, js, css). What you tried is just assigning that divs innerHTML back to itself. You need to actually use AJAX or some other approach to re-fetch the data from the Server.

Comment: you need to use AJAX to make the request to your PHP file, and on `success` change the HTML: `document.getElementById("sessioncontent").innerHTML = ajaxResponseText`

Comment: That JS line...that won't work. You're grabbing the current contents and setting them to the current contents.

Comment: set new session content to some hidden field and use bind hidden fields change event and then onchange set the div content...

Comment: @ZachL I gathered that as the php code is inside the innerHTML, assigning the same innerHTML will reload the php code

Comment: @Matt9Atkins view source on the code in the browser. the PHP is NOT in the innerHTML. Its processed output is. PHP executes server-side, before the page hits the users browser.

Comment: The client/server relationship is extremely important to understand when doing web development. You will benefit greatly from exploring a bit more "how the web works" and then moving on to reading about AJAX. Once you do that, you'll have a much better understanding on how to create a website with dynamic content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing content with the same content. I would suggest making an ajax call and then populating your div with the response from the ajax call. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: yourUrl,
  method: 'get', // or 'post'
  success: function (response) {
      $('#sessioncontent').html(response);
  }
  // other ajax options here if you need them
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Too, complicated.  First, display the initial div content w/ out the PHP code (i.e. the output of the PHP).  Second, your wording doesn't makes complete sense - JavaScript does not call PHP.  I'm going to assume you mean Ajax.  Once you get the new session variable from an ajax call, then you can update your div dynamically.

I think you are a bit fuzzy on your concepts, which is fine, I'm sure that is why you posted.